# Insert in MYSQL from document table

Tags: php, mysql, csv, ms-word

I am using php to enter data from CSV file in mysql table. One column of CSV has text data for which I cannot maintain any formatting, and so the data when displayed in the webpage does not show up in a nice way. 
I am thinking now to have the data in MS Word table and use php to insert data in mysql table from the Word table. Once again, the only advantage for me is to maintain the formatting of the data of one column.

How can I enter data from Word table in mysql table?

Comment: Using MS Word format is tricky. Can you provide an example of the data in that column so I can advise something about keeping its format?

Comment: I still don't get what is your problem :(
How exactly you want this to be formatted on the web page?

Comment: Column1_Name: Tim, Column2_Location: Amsterdam, Column3_Description: Here goes a description about Tim (up to 2000 characters). The data may or may not come with empty lines between paragraphs. I would like that when data from the mysql table is displayed on the webpage then the text appears with the empty lines. Also if a part of the data comes with bullets then the webpage should display that text with bullets.

Answer (score 0):

So according to the comments you need to format the text in the Description column using HTML.

This is not that easy task and can be very complex depending on the exact features of the formatting you need.

For example, to make new lines appear as new lines in HTML page, you will need to replace new line characters with `<br />` tags:

```
$description = str_replace("\n", "<br />", $description);
```

If you need some more complex formatting like bulleted lists or italic/bold tags you will need to implement more complex parsing and formatting code.
For bulleted lists you will need to split the content into lines (`$arr = explode("\n", $description)`), find the lines starting with a character representing the bullet (* for example, depends on your column format) and replace them with `<li>` tags. Besides that you will need an `<ul>` and `</ul>` tags marking the start and the end of the list.

Similar approach will be needed for every formatting you need to keep in HTML.

Comment: Well, if I am using word formatted text and enter it using a html form via a webpage and then use the following code to get the data: $_SESSION['Description']= $_POST['Description']; $myDescription = trim($_SESSION['Description']);
    $myDescription = nl2br(myDescription); Then I can maintain the formatting when subsequently displaying via webpage. Coming back to my question: how can I enter data into mysql table from Word table so that I can maintain the formatting?

Comment: When you copy text fragment from the Word document and paste it into the form field the browser takes the task of preserving the formatting and translating it into the HTML code.
You can't do this in your php script easily. I'd suggest to go with the CSV parsing and convert the formatting as you need.